"Possible dulicate" vs "Does this answer your question"
@ArnonWeinberg commented in Is there any evidence of a biologically predetermined, gendered psyche? that it is a possible duplicate of another question rather than close-vote it.

Possible duplicate of: Is gender biologically or socially determined?

I understand why Arnon did this, because being a site ♦️mod, the other way would immediately close the question without community vote. But, in my mind, the automatic (SE system created) comment left by my vote to close is not explicit enough as a vote to close.

Does this answer your question? Is gender biologically or socially determined?

Those new to StackExchange or those starting to understand their role in site moderating may not necessarily spot that my comment is a vote to close, where if they upvote it they are essentially adding more votes to close the question as a duplicate.
The point I am trying to make is, shouldn't the generated comment be more explicit as a vote to close rather than looking like a friendly comment?
If this issue is out of site ♦️mod control and should be raised in meta.stackexchange.com, please can a ♦️mod migrate this there?

I believe this was among the issues raised when the auto comment text changed. The explanation was that the old phrasing was somehow "unfriendly". Along with complaints that the new "too broad' close reason fails to address too broad questions that aren't also multiple questions, I felt like feedback on these issues was really discarded by staff, like they had taken too much time already on the wording to even consider changes. Maybe now they would, but yeah, this goes far beyond anything we have control over here.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339563/401068 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340788/401068 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/401068
